# batch: launch pipenv shell, then run command in the virtual environment

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, pipenv

Here is a batch script:

```
Z:
cd Z:\different_directory
pipenv shell
cd ..\another_directory


:End
cmd  /k
```

What happens here is that the pipenv shell gets launched, but the virtual environment does not cd. Instead, once I exit the pipenv, it then runs the cd command.

Is it possible to run a command from inside the pipenv using this batch script?

Answer (score 15):

You can use `pipenv run` instead of `pipenv shell` to directly run a python command or a batch script. You won't be able to run `pipenv run cd ../another_dir` directly, but I'm assuming that isn't the main goal of this since you'd only be changing the directory in that session. You can create a batch script, say test.bat, with

```
cd ../another_dir
python test.py
```

Then run it with `pipenv run test.bat`. The page below has more details.

source:
http://witkowskibartosz.com/blog/pipenv_run_vs_pipenv_shell.html#.W2SBZflKhaQ

Comment: Did you mean to say `pipenv run` and `pipenv shell` instead of `python run` and `python shell`?

Answer (score 7):

I know this question is old but if any of you found this through google, here's the exact answer: Just use `pipenv shell "/c command [args]"`, in this case `pipenv shell "/c cd ..\another_directory"`

Why this works: Like the [documentation](https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/cli/#pipenv-shell) says, whatever comes after shell will be passed as an argument to the subshell, and the argument /c on CMD runs a command on shell spawn. So there. You could even make it run a whole .bat.

Comment: `pipenv shell "cd ..\another_directory"` worked for me on Ubuntu environment