# Use a .bat file to open a pipenv virtual environment and then run commands

Tags: command-prompt, pipenv

I would like create a .bat file to cd to my working directory, start a pipenv virtual environment, and then run a series of commands in the pipenv shell command prompt.

```
#test.bat

    cd C:\testdirectory

    pipenv shell

    echo test
```

My pipenv shell starts, but the "echo test" is not executed.

Comment: Commands in the batch file after the `pipenv shell` don't execute, because they're still in the context of the command shell instead. Batch files don't work this way.

Comment: Thanks, Ken. Is there a way to automate commands for pipenv shell that you are aware of?

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to automate. See https://realpython.com/pipenv-guide/, which has a discusssion of how the shell is supposed to be used. Where exactly would you need to add automation there?

Comment: I often run the following 3 commands in series: "manage.py makemigrations [app], manage.py migrate [app], manage.py runserver." It would be great if I could create a shortcut to run these.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [batch: launch pipenv shell, then run command in the virtual environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51290808/batch-launch-pipenv-shell-then-run-command-in-the-virtual-environment)

Answer (score 1):

I created a batch file to take me to the correct folder and open the environment (as above) and then ran a second batch file which contains:

```
pipenv run python manage.py runserver
```

Answer (score 1):

I combined Marks idea of using a second bat file. with the pipenv run command.
This way you only need to run the teststart.bat file, which will execute the runtest.bat file inside the pipenv environment.

test starter bat file:

```
C:\Users\Me\Desktop\teststart.bat
    cd C:\Users\Me\my_project
    pipenv run runtest // all commands in the runtest.bat file will be inside pipenv
```

test runner bat file:

```
C:\Users\Me\my_project\runtest.bat
     echo test
     echo 'more comamnds'
     python manage.py runserver
```