# activate a virtual environment and run a command within from a bash script

Tags: bash, docker, pipenv

I am using a bash script as an entry point to a docker container. My goal is to be able to activate the virtual environment within the docker container and then run a command within from the same bash script with no manual input.
The relevant bits of the script is as follows

```
#!/bin/bash
pipenv shell
ln -s /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages
command to be run within venv
python3
```

the issue is that when pipenv shell is run the venv is activated and entered but the rest of the command does not run within it. i can manually run commands within the venv and the rest of the script waits for me to exit. How do I specify I want commands run within?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [batch: launch pipenv shell, then run command in the virtual environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51290808/batch-launch-pipenv-shell-then-run-command-in-the-virtual-environment)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `pipenv run` to directly run a `python` or `bash` script within a virtual-environment. Simply write a script that contains the commands you would like run in your environment `script.sh` and then do `pipenv run script.sh`.

Script.sh:

> ln -s /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages
>   command to be run within venv
>   python3

Then simply:
`pipenv run script.sh`

[Similar to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51290808/batch-launch-pipenv-shell-then-run-command-in-the-virtual-environment?rq=1)