# Run pipenv shell as part of a bash script

Tags: bash, shell, virtualenv, pipenv

I created a bash script to scaffold boilerplates for several apps (React, Next.js, django, etc).

In part of my `django_install()` function, I run the following (reduced here):

```
mkdir "$app_name"
cd ./"$app_name" || exit 0
gh repo clone <my-repo-boilerplate> .
rm -rf .git
pipenv install
pipenv install --dev
exit 0
```

I would also like to execute `pipenv shell` and some commands that need to run inside that virtual environment, as my boilerplate has some custom scripts that I'd like to run to automatise the script completely.

I understand I cannot just run `pipenv shell` or `python manage.py [etc...]` in my bash script.

How could I achieve it?

Comment: Why can't you run those commands ? Is it because they are interactive ?

Comment: Also, based on the code sample you posted, your `exit 0` are not needed

Comment: Unless I'm doing something wrong elswhere, the `pipenv shell` command is ran in a different shell, not within my created directory.

Comment: Although [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51290808/batch-launch-pipenv-shell-then-run-command-in-the-virtual-environment) is for batch, this may be worth looking into

Comment: I added the `exit 0` because at the very end of the script I call the init() function. Can I get rid of it still? The snippet I pasted is in an if/else inside a function.

Comment: `exit 0` will exit your script entirely (not just your function). If this is a behaviour you need, then sure, use it. You can also use `set -e` if you want your script to exit when a command fails (more info [here](https://gist.github.com/mohanpedala/1e2ff5661761d3abd0385e8223e16425))

Comment: Thanks! Yes, once that else is done, my script is finished and should exit. I'll check your link indeed!

Comment: Side-note: I didn't realise scripting could be so cool! I really love it so far! Such at time saver! I would like to see how these would work on node.js and create them as node packages. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you can use `pipenv run` for that. E.g.:

```
pipenv run python manage.py [etc...]
```

Which will run `python manage.py` within the virtual environment created by pipenv.

https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/cli.html#run