# Running a python environment and python code in that env from a bash shell script

Tags: python, shell, ubuntu, environment, pipenv

I am trying to create a @reboot entry in in a cron file to run a bash script to initialise a python virtual environment and following that run my python programs.  Before I can do that I need to be able to do this from a bash script.  My knowledge of scripting is not great, however, you have to soldier on.

I create the environment for my python programs on a day to day basis by navigating to my project folder and typing.

```
cd ~/project_folder
pipenv shell
```

The shell is running and within it I can invoke my python scripts from the cli.  In trying to automate this I tried the following in a .sh file.

```
#! /usr/bin/bash
cd ~/project_file
pipenv shell
```

When I ran the .sh script it worked, however any cli code I try following the 'pipenv shell' line is not run because the bash script is waiting for the environment to drop.  But if the environment drops I can't run the python scripts.

There is more that I am aiming to do with the scripting but this is the first hurdle I am having difficulty getting over.  Sadly, I have been on this all day and so I am now shouting out for a leg up.  If anyone could point me in the right direction I would be much obliged.

Comment: Every script runs in a separate process. When that process exits, any environment changes made in that process are lost; the parent process does not change. This is a common beginner FAQ.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12351702/how-to-write-a-bash-script-to-set-global-environment-variable and/or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464253/global-environment-variables-in-a-shell-script

Comment: Also for the problem you are apparently trying to solve, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67284203/run-pipenv-shell-as-part-of-a-bash-script

Comment: I think that ..203 has an answer I can use.  Thank you tripleee.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write a bash script to set global environment variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12351702/how-to-write-a-bash-script-to-set-global-environment-variable)

Comment: Hi Faisal,  not directly.  It's a great pointer for environment questions, but as it turned out it was more of a 'pipenv' configuration problem in the end.  Thank you for the link though - it was a more than interesting read.